# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186) Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

hope all are well.
As a heads up, I am still learning and am still very new to flutter and Dart so, if my code looks really stupid, that's why.

I am trying to get data from a specific doc from Firestore. Then display as a List tile. I am trying to save the data into a local variable(List), which I them use to make the list.

but I get an error, the error doesn't tell where the it occurs which makes it hard to fix.
Here is the function and the variables.

```
 final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
  List<PhoneModel> _phones = [];

  Future<void> _getPhones() async {
    var phones = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('phones')
        .doc('5AfeF8xkdbM2xgXheDaK5OcDeT63')
        .get();

    List<PhoneModel> loadedPhones = [];
    phones.data().forEach((key, value) {
      loadedPhones.add(PhoneModel(
          descriptions: value['description'],
          price: value['Price'],
          title: value['Title'],
          id: key));
      _phones = loadedPhones;

      return _phones;
    });
  }
```

here is the error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter (32763): #0      _UserPhoneAddsState._getPhones.<anonymous closure>
package:secondhandphones/…/CreateEditPhone/UpdatePhone.dart:32
E/flutter (32763): #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
E/flutter (32763): #2      _UserPhoneAddsState._getPhones
package:secondhandphones/…/CreateEditPhone/UpdatePhone.dart:30
E/flutter (32763): <asynchronous suspension>
```

EDIT: Here is the Phone Model class as per the comment

```
class PhoneModel {
  final String title;
  final String id;
  final String descriptions;
  final num price;

  PhoneModel({
    this.descriptions,
    this.id,
    this.price,
    this.title,
  });
}
```

Please tell me if I need to post anything else
Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show your PhoneModel Class

Comment: Added the class

Comment: you cant use FOREACH when you just get one document 

foreach is used on a query.

Comment: What should I use instead

Comment: Are you sure all of the values you are adding in the new instance match the types you declared in the model?